# Using 3rd Party JS library in LWR Community

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, experience-cloud, lwr, lws

I need to use a 3rd patty JS library in my LWC component in a LWR community. Looks like platformResourceLoader is not working in LWR, so it's not possible to load script from static resources as usually, it throws error "lwr_bootstrap_locker:14 Not allowed to load local resource: blob".
I tried to load the script manually

```
const libraryScript = document.createElement('script');
libraryScript.src = scriptURL;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(this.libraryScript);
```

It causes the same error.

I try to load the script directly in a community head

`<script src="/sfsites/c/resource/LibraryFolder/library.js"></script>`

and then call it from my LWC, like I do with script loaded by platformResourceLoader

`window.libraryFunc();`

But LWC doesn't see this func in window var(there is no typo, the same function works in Lightning).

Only one way that I found is to add two scripts to the head, the first one loads the library and the second adds listener to the document and calls my function on cathing event

```
<script src="/sfsites/c/resource/LibraryFolder/library.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener('myevent', (event) =>  libraryFunc(event.detail));
</script>
```

and then dispatch this event from my LWC

```
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("myevent", {detail}));
```

It works for me, but it looks like a dirty hack, is there a better solution to use the JS library in a LWR site?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own version of `platformResourceloader`

```
import jquery from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jquery';
...
connectedCallback(){
...
this.loadScript(jquery);
//instead of loadScript(this, jquery);
...
}
...

loadScript(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        script.charset = 'utf-8';
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        script.addEventListener('load', resolve);
        script.addEventListener('error', reject);
    })
}
```

Alternatively you can host the Script outside Salesforce and try accessing it within LWR via [privileged scripts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/advanced_privileged_script.htm).

Make use of the tag